# How to track a specific email using Amazon's Simple Email Service?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-sns, amazon-ses

I am successfully sending emails using the AWS SDK for Java and I can also retrieve the Message ID for each email. Now I need to track the email to see if it was successfully delivered or it bounced.

Is there a way to use that Message ID to track the status of a specific email?

I have explored the getSendStatistics API but this only gives statistics for all emails, ideally I need something to track individual emails.

Is there a way to track individual emails using an SES API or even a Simple Notification Service API?

Comment: You can use [Amazon SES Notifications through Amazon SNS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/notifications-via-sns.html) for that. You create SNS topic subscriptions depending how you want to track the deliveries and bounces.

Comment: Would that give me tracking as well as the MessageID's?

Comment: The SNS [notification content](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/notification-contents.html) itself contains a `mail` object that has the message ID, a `delivery` object for successful deliveries, a `bounce` object for bounced recipients and a `complaint` object for complained recipients (if any).

Comment: Oh very nice, thank you. If you put that as an answer I can accept this question as answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Amazon SES Notifications through Amazon SNS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/notifications-via-sns.html) for that. You create SNS topic subscriptions depending how you want to track the deliveries and bounces.

The SNS [notification content](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/notification-contents.html) itself contains a `mail` object that has the message ID, a `delivery` object for successful deliveries, a `bounce` object for bounced recipients and a `complaint` object for complained recipients (if any).